# Reloading DIV taking too long using jquery .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div that contains some data from a database and a form that updates the quantity of certain items. When the form is submitted the div refreshes and while it's refreshing a modal pops up with a bootstrap spinner to show that it's loading.

The problem i'm having is that sometimes it take a while for the div to refresh so the loading modal hides, it looks like nothing is happening, the user carries on and then the refresh happens.

Is there a way to check if the refresh has happened and then hide the modal based on that?

Otherwise the only option I see is to set the timeout to a silly number and just hope the refresh has happened in that time.

```
function updateQuantity(updateID) {
    $('#spinnerModal').modal('show');
    var updateQtyID = updateID.getAttribute('updateID');
    var updateQtyForm = 'form.cuttingListItem' + updateQtyID;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_script_ajax_updateQuantity.php",
        data: $(updateQtyForm).serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $("#statusDiv").load(location.href + " #statusDiv");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#spinnerModal').modal('hide');
            }, 1000);
        }
    }); 
};
```

Comment: did u try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp) which says the load function has a callback? btw using setTImeout is not at all a way in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function has an optional complete function parameter that runs when the load is complete, so you can do this:

```
function updateQuantity(updateID) {
    $('#spinnerModal').modal('show');
    var updateQtyID = updateID.getAttribute('updateID');
    var updateQtyForm = 'form.cuttingListItem' + updateQtyID;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_script_ajax_updateQuantity.php",
        data: $(updateQtyForm).serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $("#statusDiv").load(location.href + " #statusDiv", function(){
                $('#spinnerModal').modal('hide');
            });
        }
    }); 
};
```